# Facebook Graph API Rate Limits CORS X-App-Usage header access

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how X-App-Usage header is meant to be read from javascript CORS request response if most of the headers are hidden since the server does not return required Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.

Comment: I guess using all other request options beside javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Request headers visibility at client side depends on CORS Policy defined at Server. Since you can read them with the browser (a client) you should be able to fetch them with Javascript.

Note that Facebook only provide these headers if you exceed their limits. See Picture.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but they are not response the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header to allow us to use from Javascript.